# Error for input/output system

Tags: java

i've gotten this problem multiple times and it's probably the easiest thing in the world to fix, but for some reason I can't.

JCreator expects '{' on the class line, even though there's one there already. I've tried moving it and doing all sorts of things, but I can't figure it out. I fixed it before by making it not public, but it didn't work this time. Please help.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class project 3 4 {

public static void main(String [] args)
{
Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

int employeeID;

double regularPay;

double regularHoursWorked;

double regularMoneyEarned;

double overtimeHoursWorked;

double overtimePay;

double totalPay;

System.out.print ("Employee ID");
employeeID = reader.nextInt();
System.out.print ("Enter Wage");
regularPay = nextDouble();
System.out.print ("Enter Hours Worked");
regularHoursWorked = nextDouble();
System.out.print ("Enter Overtime Hours Worked");
overtimeHoursWorked = nextDouble();

overtimePay = 1.5 * regularPay;
regularMoneyEarned = regularPay * regularHoursWorked;
totalPay = overtimePay + regularMoneyEarned;

System.out.print ("Your total pay = " + totalPay);
```

Comment: Aren't you missing closing tag at the end? `}`, also that's not JavaScript.

Answer (score 3):

That line should be `public class project34 {` or `public class project {`.  JCreator is probably getting tripped up by the space

Answer (score 0):

your class name contains spaces which is not valid:

```
public class project 3 4 {
```

try changing it to:

```
public class project34 {
```